# PERC H200i "ignoring" some disks in RAID 10 resulting in slow IO

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

I have a Dell PE T710 with a PERC H200i that has a single array of 6x 500GB SATA disks +1 hot spare.

This server (and its disks) have been running flawlessly for a few years.  Today I began getting alerts for high IO wait times on that server.  I investigated and the disk array was inexplicably slow.  There were no applications pushing any more than a minimal level of IO, and at about 22 MB/s of linear read or write (using dd) it would reach saturation and I'd start seeing 100% IO wait in top.  This array had been previously capable of 250MB/s in that same situation.

Nothing has been changed either in hardware or software for weeks.

At any rate, it looks like a hardware issue:  Observing the array physically, I only see activity (blinking LEDs) on 4 of the 6 disks in the array.  However, in OMSA the array is reported as fully functional.  I rebooted, went into the controller's BIOS and again, the array is fine by all appearances.  I updated the f/w to 07.03.06.00 A10, and that didn't help.

"Blinking" the HDD LEDs via OMSA did work, so it's not as if it's just a case of bad LEDs on the apparently non-functional drives.

I then started a consistency check on the array, and so far it hasn't complained, but I still only see activity on 4 of the 6 disks.

I've never seen this before, where a RAID controller seemingly stops using 2 disks while simultaneously reporting those same disks as being OK and part of the array.

My assumption is that I need to replace the H200 and/or those disks.

However, I'm curious to know if anyone has seen this behavior before, and if there is an alternate solution.

Is there any way to get transparency into the actual utilization of an individual disk using the H200?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**  These disks are Dell certified, however their firmware was never updated and was circa 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the two "non responsive" disks solved the problem.  The two mirror sets rebuilt, and now all 6 disks are showing activity appropriately.  Linear write speed was 257 MB/s after rebuild completion, as should be usual for this array.

However, when tested in a USB enclosure, the two "failed" disks had no SMART errors and gave R/W speeds around 100 MB/s, which is around what I'd expect for 7200 RPM SATA disks.  Hence I can't say that they *failed*, but rather that the controller stopped using them.

I haven't found a way [in CentOS] to monitor individual disk utilization, other than by physically looking at the LEDs.

Comment: I understand that this is a satisfactory answer as to **how** to solve the problem, but not to **why** it happened in the first place.  Frankly it's frightening that two disks can silently fall into disuse on an H200, with the only indication being lack of activity on the LED on the front of the machine.

I will update this answer with any other info gleaned from any comments, and/or from my own testing.